# At what troop level is GOWIPE an effective attack option?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm at TH8 and have all of the troop options unlocked for my town hall level, although they're not necessarily upgraded yet. Generally, at what point is GOWIPE (Golems, Wizards, Pekkas) an effective attacking option?  For my personal situation, I have level 4 wizards and level 1 Golems and Pekkas, along with level 5 rage and level 4 healing.

I realize all questions like this typically depend on the base being attacked. I'm looking for a general guideline on when I can expect a GOWIPE attack to be effective if the base I'm targeting warrants such an attack. I'm looking for things like:

- Are level 1 Golems/Pekkas effective enough?
- Should wizards absolutely be at level 5 or higher? (they get huge gains at level 5)
- Is GOWIPE even effective at TH8?
- Other relevant info to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOWIPE is definitely a good strategy at TH8. When I maxed my troops at TH8 I used it to loot Dark Elixir, worked well.

You will definitely see a big difference when you use level 5 wiz, they are meant to do a lot of work together with the PEKKAs, so having them at a higher level will help.

Consideration: do not drop all your troops at once, PEKKAS do not have a favourite target so they may instead go wiping out perimeter buildings instead of going for the centre. So clear up some space using some wizards first, or even some archers. After that you can safely drop your PEKKAs and king to funnel them towards the core/loot.

Another strategy is dragons with three lightning spells. If you plan out your attack well you can always get at least a two star, and 3 star on non tricky bases. This strategy is elixir hungry so would recommend it for war or trophy pushing and not farming.

Comment: Are level 1 PEKKAS/Golems sufficient to use GOWIPE or should they be upgraded as well before getting solid use out of it?

Comment: Honestly, they are not powerful enough to use for a strong attack. However, if you are attacking town halls lower than yours e.g TH7 then maybe they may do some good work there. Best thing to do is to try it yourself, and watch them get stronger at attacking as you upgrade them. Have fun!

Comment: So I have a lot more experience with GOWIPE at TH8, particularly at maxed out TH8. Definitely a solid strategy, sometimes more effective than dragons. Speaking of dragons, with dark spells a thing now, 1 rage + 2 lightning + 1 earthquake is a more optimal loadout for an all dragon attack. Having that rage around is great for getting to the air defense towers you didn't destroy with spell damage.

Answer (score 2):

As per TH8 you need minimum of lvl5 Wiz, lvl2 Pekka, lvl1 Golem lvl5 WB.

For Golem if you don't have lvl2 means that's okay. For pekka lvl2 is okay and lvl 3 is good. Wiz should be 5 for effective attack.

The Army combo is

1. 2 Golem
2. 2 Pekka
3. 7 Wallbreakers
4. 19 Wizards
5. lvl4 or lvl5 Pekka from Clan Castle + Poison spell
6. 2 healing + 1 rage spell + 1 Poison spell

As said above don't deploy your whole army at once. And hold few wizards for using it in critical conditions when they need or wiping corner building. Because group of wiz will die in single giant bomb.

Comment: "lvl4 or lvl4 + Pekka from Clan Castle + Poison spell" Do you mean a level 3 or level 4 Pekka?

Comment: @Ellesedil Level4 or if possible Level5(max) pekka. If your clan member have level4 and your clan lvl is 5 means you will receive lvl5 pekka which is powerful. But minimum is lvl4 pekka from CC.

Comment: Cool. You should edit your answer and fix the typo then and add that additional info.

Comment: @Ellesedil Actually I meant lvl4+ Pekka :). Anyway edited.

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 golem, 4 PEKKAs, 14 wizards, 3 WBs, and 3 archers is good army comp for GOWIPE. 2 Heals and a Rage+Poison, and I find that haste spells help in cc as well as extra Pekka. If you are in th9, you can carry more haste spells as well. You can carry 2 golems, but I think 1 is better not only since golems are expensive, but also because 1 golem is enough to break into the core. After the core is destroyed, most of your wizards are probably dead anyway, so more Pekkas will be better in the 3-star attack. Also, so many WBs are unnecessary, I find three will work to help funnel and then the pekkas will quickly destroy internal walls. If you desperately need to destroy that many walls, just use earthquake instead of heal.

Comment: While good advice, this doesn’t actually answer the question about what troop level you need for GoWiPe